# Regular expression (0+1)*1(0+1)*0 DFA

Tags: automation

I'm trying to understand the regular expression: (0+1)*1(0+1)*0 Could you provide examples that matches this pattern?

Comment: You can use an online regex debugger like this: https://regex101.com/ to see what it does and test strings against it

Comment: Basically your expression says this: it can start with zero or more times of multiple zeroes and a 1 (01, 000001, or 001 are all valid for this subexpression as is an empty expression), then it must have the single digit 1, then once more 0 or more expressions of multiple 0's terminated by the digit 1 and the entire expression needs to terminate with 0. So the following all match: 10, 00110, 0110010 . As for the parentheses, they mark groups of interest for individual capture.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain :

```
1 - (0+1) mean any number of 0, then a 1
2 - (0+1)* means the previous line any number of times (can be 0)
3 - (0+1)*1 mean the previous line and a 1
4 - (0+1)*0 means line 2 and a 0
```

10 works : 0 times (0+1), then a 1, then 0 times (0+1), then a 0.
00000000000100000000000110 works : eleven 0 and a 1, twice (this is (0+1)*). Then, a 1. Then, no (0+1), and the last 0. A few other examples :

```
10
00001000010000110000100001000010
01010110
0110
```

I hope you understood (I'm not english, my english is bad, sorry)

EDIT : There are a lot of websites that can help you with regular expressions, whether it is learning or testing regex.

Comment: Could you show me a graph that matches this pattern?